# How To Store/Manage Multiple Values Under Single Value In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my first question here.

Scenario:

I have a list of newspapers, say:

```
NYT
NJYT
CIT
DIT
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

Each newspaper has several editions depending on the region of publication. For eg,

```
1. NYT has michigan, atlanta, chicago, newyork, arizona..c
2. NJYT has florida, california, washington, michigan, atlanta, chicago, newyork
3. and so on........
```

Requirement:

I want to group multiple editions under each newspaper and store it in the database. How can I achieve this?
Currently, I have a table named Publications with the following columns:

```
JournalID   varchar(10) 
JournalFullName varchar(50) 
JournalShortName    varchar(20) 
Language    varchar(20) 
[No of Editions]    int 
Since_Year  date    
City_of_Origin  varchar(50)
```

I'm very new to SQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SQL has its own terms-of-art which once you know them will make it easier to search for answers (your question concerns "database normalization"). Good ways to learn about SQL are through books and tutorial web sites. If you like using books, you could search for "stackoverflow best sql book" to get some recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have a separate editions table, something like:

```
create table Editions (
    EditionsId int not null identity(1, 1) primary key,
    JournalId varchar(10) references Publications(JournalId),
    EditionName varchar(255),
    . . .
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an edition table referencing the Journal table, so that you can have multiple editions for a journal. Something close to;

```
CREATE TABLE Edition (
    EditionId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    JournalId VARCHAR(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Publication(JournalId), 
    EditionName VARCHAR(50)
);
```

This lets an edition reference a publication, which means that you can have multiple editions referencing the *same* publication.

This is also known as a [one-to-many relationship](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/25122/one-to-many-relationship).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the scope of the app, it is possible also to store the editions array as a json encoded text field, which is the simplest way to encode an array to a string. You just need to remember to json_decode it when you need to display your data.

Next think you know, you'll be reading about NoSQL solutions :grin: